# Java Sockets over the Internet: ConnectException (operation timed out)

Tags: java, networking

I'm trying to open a socket to a website over the Internet, but can't.  After about a minute, a `ConnectException` is thrown saying that the operation timed out.

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("gmail.com"), 25);
```

My computer is connected to a router, which is connected to the Internet.  My router is configured to direct all incoming port 25 data to port 2550 on my local machine (192.168.2.2).  So, I thought maybe if I set the "local address" and "local port" parameters on the `Socket` constructor it might work...but this also gives me an "operation timed out" error.

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("gmail.com"), 25, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.2"), 2550);
```

I saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078018/java-sockets-the-internet), but was wondering if anyone could shed any more light on the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Your router configuration is for *incoming* connections only, not outgoing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to connect to port 25 on `gmail.com`, but that machine is not an email server. You must first look up the MX record for `gmail.com`, and then try to connect to one of the delivery servers mentioned in the returned MX record.

For example, with `dig mx gmail.com` on my machine, I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5 <<>> mx gmail.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34063
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.                     IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.              1697    IN      MX      30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              1697    IN      MX      40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              1697    IN      MX      5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              1697    IN      MX      10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              1697    IN      MX      20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
gmail.com.              266895  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
gmail.com.              266895  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
gmail.com.              266895  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
gmail.com.              266895  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.         262525  IN      A       216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.         262525  IN      A       216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.         262525  IN      A       216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.         262525  IN      A       216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 65 msec
;; SERVER: 144.52.10.15#53(144.52.10.15)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 28 14:30:04 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 295
```

So try connecting to port 25 on `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` (which is the server with the lowest MX priority number).

Comment: @NayukiMinase Or JNDI with the DNS provider.

Comment: Wooo!! That worked!  But gmail marked my email as spam. :'(  Are MX records part of SMTP?  I'm trying to write an SMTP server and thought that sending emails would just be a matter of opening a socket to the host part of the email (the part after the "@").  I got the server part working though, so at least I can receive emails.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, MX is part of the SMTP specification. See [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt).

Comment: @GregHewgill Do you know if it's better to use port 25 or 587?  I think that 587 is supposed to be the new standard.

Comment: Those two ports are for different purposes. In general, incoming connections on port 25 are treated as "outside" connections, for mail delivery to local users. Connections on port 587 are treated as connections from users of the local domain, intending to send mail somewhere else. Gmail requires the use of port 587 for Gmail users sending mail, because it requires authentication for all connections on port 587. A lot of the problems with SMTP such as "open relays" have their roots in the use of port 25 for both purposes.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to receive the mail messages sent from Google to your router?  That's the only reason to forward incoming traffic from port 25 to 2550.  If you want to do that then you're going to need to use a ServerSocket to receive the incoming connection on your 192.168.2.2 server.  What you're having problems with is that Socket initiates a connection to a server.  It's a client socket.  A ServerSocket waits for incoming connections.  Do a little research in how ServerSockets work, but if you really want to receive incoming connections you'll have to implement the SMTP protocol which is no small feat.  There are SMTP libraries out there that you could reuse.  Check the Apache James project which is like Servlets for Mail servers.

http://james.apache.org/

Comment: Yes, I actually got the SMTP "server" part working.  So, I can send an email from my Gmail account and my SMTP server will properly receive it.  It's actually not too complicated...I was able to write a program that receives emails just by reading the SMTP Wikipedia page.  I'm creating an SMTP server from scratch because I want to learn how email works.